# Select children of sibling of a element in pure CSS

Tags: css

Say you have:

```
----------
    A
----------
    B -> C
----------
```

Given C is children of B, i want to select all Cs which have a parent B that is sibling of A

Comment: A + B > C. + stands for adjacent sibling and > stand for child

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
A ~ B > C
```

returns all 'C's that are a child of 'B' that is a sibling of 'A'

@Sven also mentioned the '+' adjacent sibling selector which will also work if A and B are 'adjacent' siblings (meaning right next to each other and not divided by other sibling elements.)

Answer (score 0):

```
.a +.b .c
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAu2Z/) where you can test. Notice how the `.c` divs that don't match the rule don't get the green background. I wouldn't count on IE to support this though.

Comment: that is wrong. in your example c must not be a direct child of b

Comment: He didn't say he wanted C to be a *direct* child.

Comment: he said 'Given C is children of B'. For me that sounds like a direct child